# rcpコマンドの戻り値で成功可否、ファイル有無を判断したい

Tags: linux

シェルスクリプト内で、rcpコマンドを記述し、サーバ間のファイルを移動した場合、成功したか、瞬断等で異常終了したか、ファイルが無かったか、を戻り値で判断したいのですが、どのような方法で実現可能ですか？

※社内環境によりrcpを使わざるを得ないです。

コマンドの知識が浅く曖昧な質問で申し訳ありませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 に附属の rcp コマンド(rsh-client パッケージ)のソースコード(`rcp.c,v 1.15 2000/07/23 04:16:22 dholland Exp`)を眺める限り、exit status は `0`(success), `1`(fault) などとなっていて、エラー原因の種別までは分かりません。rcp コマンドは stderr(標準エラー出力)にエラーメッセージを出力しますので、それを取得して判断する方が適切かと思います。例えば、ソースコード内には `(void)fprintf(stderr, "rcp: lost connection\n");` などが見受けられます。

Comment: `rcp` は名前の通りファイルをコピーするコマンドなので移動には使えません。「ファイルの有無」とはコピー元、コピー先のどちらを指していますか？